# Is casting char to int a safe operation in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Given the following code:

```
string source = "Some Unicode String";
foreach( char value in source ) {

    int y = (int)value;

}
```

Is it possible that the cast from char to int could fail (and under what circumstances)?

Comment: short answer, no (none.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A conversion from `char` to `int` will not fail, with any `char` value.

From [.NET 4.0 reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx)

> The .NET Framework uses the Char structure to represent a Unicode
>   character. The Unicode Standard identifies each Unicode character with
>   a unique 21-bit scalar number called a code point, and defines the
>   UTF-16 encoding form that specifies how a code point is encoded into a
>   sequence of one or more 16-bit values. Each 16-bit value ranges from
>   hexadecimal 0x0000 through 0xFFFF and is stored in a Char structure.
>   **The value of a Char object is its 16-bit numeric (ordinal) value**.

Answer (score 8):

No, it is not possible it could fail. A [char](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) ranges from 0x0 to 0xFFFF (65535), while an [int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx) ranges from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, so all values of char fall inside the range of int.